# How to network a Mac running System 7.6 with Mac OS X 10.6 or Windows Vista over Ethernet?

Tags: macos

The title pretty much says it all.  I have a Powerbook 540c that is connected to my network via Ethernet.  It has no Internet tools on it at all, and its running System 7.6.

I am trying to figure out a way to get it to mount a drive on either my Windows Vista workstation or my Snow Leopard Macbook.  Once I do that I can get an old browser on there and get what I need off the Internet.

Thus far I have not been able to get it connected.  Microsoft dropped Appletalk support in XP and despite enabling Appletalk on my Macbook, the powerbook cannot see it in the Chooser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure this is a proper question for stackoverflow, I'll post a couple links to get you started towards solving the problem. ;)

http://www.vintagemacworld.com/mactcpip.html
http://main.system7today.com/articles/leopard/tutorial1/index.html